# Tools to help implementing SQLite based persistence for Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Do you know any tools that may help to implement basic SQLite-based persistence in an Android app? Or even tools that may ease the process of building content providers?

I've had quite a few projects, most of them saved persistent data into SQLite tables, some thru content providers. Mostly I needed basic CRUD operations, so the task to implement all this stuff was quite repetitve, and slow. I wondered if there are any eclipse plugins / standalone tools that could help with this?

By tedious tasks I mean things like:
- Writing db schemas by hand
- Administration when you need to put a new attribute into a table's schema (new string constants for the names, updating the modifier methods, etc.)
- Generating basic CRUD methods for the db
- Supporting these operations in a Content Provider
- and so on

I think it'd be nice to have some graphical tool/wizard to help generate all this stuff.

Thanks

Comment: don't forget to tick accepted answer on the left..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [MOTODEV](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/features/) Studio for Android.It has a Database Management feature to conveniently view and edit SQLite databases on emulated devices.